# Img Src function in popup with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would to embed in my popup an image with the *img src* function.

How could I proceed in google apps script?

```
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+ copyId +"";
  var htmlString = "<base target=\"_blank\">" +
  "<h2><a href=\"" + url + "\">Open Doc!</a></h2>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlString);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Very Good!')
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+ copyId +"";
var htmlString = "<base target=\"_blank\">" +
"<h2><a href=\"" + url + "\">Open Doc!</a></h2>" +
"<p><img src='https://www.gstatic.com/script/apps_script_1x_48dp.png' /></p>";
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlString);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Very Good!')
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks.